# Get text while not EOF

Tags: c, string, text, char, eof

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define N 256

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char testo[N];
    int i;
    printf("PER TERMINARE L'INSERIMENTO PREMERE CTRL+Z oppure CTRL+D \n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&testo[i]);
        /* if(testo[i]=='h' && testo[i-1]=='c')
        {
            i--;
            testo[i]='k';
        }
        if(testo[i]==testo[i-1])
        {
            i--;
        } */
        if(testo[i]==EOF)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    puts(testo);

    return 0;
}
```

When the code in `/* ... */` is compiled, I can't stop the insert of text with EOF, but when the code is built and run as shown here, the EOF works.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Better yet, read an entire line using `getline` or at least `fgets`

Comment: `if (testo[i] == EOF)` works by coincidence is type `char` type is signed.  It would also mistakenly detect end of file when reading the character `\377`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're testing for EOF incorrectly.  With `scanf()`, you need to look at the return value.  In fact, with almost all input functions, you need to test, if not capture and test, the return value.

Superficially, you need:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if (scanf("%c", &testo[i]) == EOF)
        break;
    …
}
```

However, in general, you should check that `scanf()` made as many successful conversions as you requested, so it is better to write:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if (scanf("%c", &testo[i]) != 1)
        break;
    …
}
```

In this example, it really won't matter.  If you were reading numeric data, though, it would matter.  The user might type `Z` instead of a number, and `scanf()` would return 0, not EOF.

Answer (score 1):

To detect `EOF`, check the result of `scanf()`

```
if scanf("%c",&testo[i]) == EOF) break;
```

---

Note: `testo[]` may not be null character terminated.  To print as a string, insure it is.

```
char testo[N];
int i;

// for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
for(i=0;i<(N-1);i++) {
  if (scanf("%c",&testo[i]) == EOF) break;
}

testo[i] = '\0';  // add
puts(testo);
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop at end of file, check the return value from `scanf`:

`scanf` returns the number of inputs correctly parsed.  In your case, `%c` reads a byte from the stream correctly as long as end of file has not been reached. `if (scanf("%c",&testo[i]) != 1) break;` will do.

Yet using `scanf` to read one byte at a time from the input stream is overkill.  The idiomatic way to do this in C is using the `getchar()` or the `getc()` function.  The return value must be stored in an `int` variable and has special value `EOF` upon end of file.

You should also make the array 1 byte longer and store a null byte at the end to make it a C string, as expected by `puts`.

Here is a modified version of your program:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char testo[N+1];
    int i;

    printf("PER TERMINARE L'INSERIMENTO PREMERE CTRL+Z oppure CTRL+D\n");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int c = getchar();
        if (c == EOF)
            break;
        testo[i] = c;
        /* ... further processing ... */
    }
    testo[i] = '\0';

    puts(testo);
    return 0;
}
```